# Converting pmml file for random forest in python

Tags: python, random-forest, pmml

I need to convert my random forest model into pmml format in python. I've imported sklearn2pmml from github and tried create a pmml file. I run the code below;

```
import pandas
import sklearn_pandas

iris = iris.csv

iris_df = pandas.concat((pandas.DataFrame(iris.data[:, :], columns = ["Sepal.Length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width"]), pandas.DataFrame(iris.target, columns = ["species"])), axis = 1)

iris_mapper = sklearn_pandas.DataFrameMapper([('sepal_length',None),
                                              ('sepal_width', None), 
                                              ('petal_width', None),
                                              ('petal_width', None),
                                              ('species',None)])

iris = iris_mapper.fit_transform(iris_df)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

iris_X = iris[:, 0:4]
iris_y = iris[:, 4]

iris_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
iris_classifier.fit(iris_X, iris_y)

from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml

sklearn2pmml(iris_classifier, iris_mapper, "randomforest.pmml")
```

However, I get an error;

```
TypeError: The pipeline object is not an instance of PMMLPipeline
```

Any suggestion what I am missing or another way to creat pmml format?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: The pipeline object is not an instance of PMMLPipeline

The first argument of the `sklearn2pmml` function call must be an instance of `sklearn2pmml.PMMLPipeline`. You're passing an instance of `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier` instead.

> Any suggestion what I am missing or another way to creat pmml format?

You're pairing a pre-historic code example with the latest version of the sklearn2pmml library. These are your options:

1. Upgrade code example to latest sklearn2pmml library version. Please take two minutes to read through [the "Usage" section of its README.file](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml#usage).
2. Downgrade the sklearn2pmml library to 0.13.0 (or older) version.

Answer (score 0):

`sklearn2pmml()` need a `PMMLPipeline` model, so try to pack `iris_classifier` with `PMMLPipeline`   like this:

```
import pandas
import sklearn_pandas
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn2pmml.pipeline import PMMLPipeline
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
d = load_iris()
iris_X = d.data
iris_y = d.target

iris_classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10)
#rfc_model = iris_classifier.fit(iris_X, iris_y)
pipeline_model = PMMLPipeline([('iris_classifier', 
iris_classifier)]).fit(iris_X, iris_y)
from sklearn2pmml import sklearn2pmml
sklearn2pmml(pipeline_model, 'rfc.pmml', with_repr = True)
```